# how to get HTML tags without rendering from ${model} in spring

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring

i have comment field where i can enter comment, consider am entering html tag like

`<h1> hello </h1>`

when page is loading its showing as

## hello

and rendering `<h1>` tag.

how to Stop page from rendering HTML tags

Am using jsp page with jstl to dispay comment.

```
textarea  class="dropdownlist" id="commentbox" onkeyup="isMaxLength(this,500)">${view.data['comment']}
```

Comment: jsp/jstl only adds a meta-data/post-factum generated tags/logic which can be readed by taglibs and in some phase it simply converts all things to HTML tags. How do you want use JSP/JSTL without rendering html?

Comment: So what is the work around,  all the am entering comments that have html tags,  getting rendered when it's displaying that comment

Answer (score 0):

You may use JSTL [`c:out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag:

```
<c:out value="${view.data['comment']}" />
```

or JSTL [`fn:escapeXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function:

```
${fn:escapeXml(view.data['comment'])}
```

Of course, you should add proper `taglib` directive to JSP (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html))